# Type mismatch when calling sprite::Scene::draw

Tags: rust, rust-piston

I am working on a personal project using Piston and Sprite. The [example code](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston-examples/blob/master/src/sprite.rs) calls this method:

```
scene.draw(c.transform, g);
```

I am trying to call a method to draw everything.
I first tried:

```
draw<G: Graphics>(&self, c: &Context, g: &mut G, scene: &mut Scene)
```

Then the compiler tells me I need to give a type parameter to the `Scene` so I tried this:

```
draw<G: Graphics, S>(&self, c: &Context, g: &mut G, scene: &mut Scene<S>)
```

Then the compiler tells me that the type needs to implements trait `ImageSize` so I tried this :

```
draw<G: Graphics, S: ImageSize>(&self, c: &Context, g: &mut G, scene: &mut Scene<S>)
```

Then I got this error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<G as graphics::Graphics>::Texture == S`
  --> src/game.rs:38:15
   |
38 |         scene.draw(c.transform, g);
   |               ^^^^ expected associated type, found type parameter
   |
   = note: expected type `<G as graphics::Graphics>::Texture`
          found type `S`
```

I don't understand what the compiler is trying to say here. The full type of `Scene` is `sprite::Scene<piston_window::Texture<gfx_device_gl::Resources>>` 
but I don't want to write that in the method's signature.

I have two questions then:

1. What is the compiler trying to tell me?
2. How can I pass the scene to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `draw` is:

```
impl<I: ImageSize> Scene<I> {
    fn draw<B: Graphics<Texture = I>>(&self, t: Matrix2d, b: &mut B)
}
```

In words, this roughly corresponds to:

When `Scene` is parameterized with a type `I` that implements `ImageSize`, the function `draw` will be available. `draw` is parameterized with a type `B` which must implement the trait `Graphics` with the associated type `Texture` set to the *same* type as `I`. The `draw` function is a method on a reference to a `Scene` and takes two more arguments: `t`, a `Matrix2d` and `b`, a mutable reference to whatever concrete type `B` is.

To be able to call `draw`, your function needs to have the same restrictions, but you are not restricting `S` to be the same as `Graphics::Texture`. Doing so allows the code to compile:

```
extern crate sprite;
extern crate graphics;

use graphics::{Graphics, ImageSize, Context};
use sprite::Scene;

struct X;
impl X {
    fn draw<G>(&self, c: &Context, g: &mut G, scene: &mut Scene<G::Texture>)
    where
        G: Graphics,
    {
        scene.draw(c.transform, g);
    }
}

fn main() {}
```